# Prevent redux useSelector from re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I have a component that uses React-Redux's `useSelector` hook to retrieve a dictionary in the Redux store. The dictionary is a map of UUIDs to objects containing data that I am rendering.

```js
interface IComponentProps {
  id: string
}

const Component: React.FC<IComponentProps> = (props) => {
  const dataMap = useSelector((store: IRootState) => store.data.value)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{dataMap[props.id].title}</h1>
      <p>{dataMap[props.id].description}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have a dispatch method that adds a new key-value pair to the data dictionary in the redux store.

Say I have multiple of these `<Component />`, and another `<ComponentTwo />` that dispatches the method to add a new key-value pair. When the dispatch method happens, all my `<Component />` will rerender even though I don't want them as their perspective title and description stay the same. Is there a way for me to disable the rerendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a memoized selector with `createSelector` from [Redux-Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector) ([`reselect`](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect)) that uses the `id` prop as part of its selection and result memoization process.

See [How do I create a selector that takes an argument?](https://reselect.js.org/FAQ#how-do-i-create-a-selector-that-takes-an-argument)

Example:

```js
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
// or if not using Redux-Toolkit
// import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

export const selectDataById = createSelector(
  [
    (state: IRootState) => state.data.value,
    (state: IRootState, id: string) => id
  ],
  (dataMap, id) => dataMap[id],
);
```

The `selectDataById` selector function will only recompute its output value when either of the input selectors' value changes. If the computed output value doesn't change then consuming components should not be triggered to rerender.

```
import { selectDataById } from '../path/to/selectDataById';

interface IComponentProps {
  id: string
}

const Component = ({ id }: IComponentProps) => {
  const data = useSelector((state: IRootState) => selectDataById(state, id));

  // check/handle undefined data reference?

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data?.title}</h1>
      <p>{data?.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I'm reading the documentation for createSelector but I'm confused about how the array of input selectors works. Is the first input selector result `(state: IRootState) => state.data.value` passed in as the dataMap parameter and the second input selector result `(state: IRootState, id: string) => id` passed in as id?

Comment: @howranwin Yes, that's basically it. The results of selectors, e.g. the outputs, can be used as inputs to other selectors. To try and save you debugging headaches in the future, use caution what you use as input selectors, if you create a cycle then the app can freeze and you won't have any error to help figure out what happened.

Comment: What do you mean by a cycle of input selectors?

Comment: @howranwin Like a dependency cycle. SelectorA uses SelectorC, SelectorB uses SelectorA, SelectorC uses SelectorB. Depending on what the computed output is from one it can lead to a cascading effect where each just get stuck recomputing their value because an input changed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi, I just tinkered with this a bit more but I could also achieve the same result by doing `useSelector((store: IRootState) => store.data.value[props.id])`, without the createSelector.